# player position bending collides with wall

Tags: lance

I want my player position to be forcefully set to a new position behind a static wall. On clients even with position bending at 1.0 the players smash into the wall rather than go through to the other side. Refreshing the page to clear previous position context fixes it so they appear in the correct side of the wall.

How can I resolve this without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky question, because Lance is focussed on physical objects which bounce around in a physical space.

You may need to delete the original game object and create a new one.